# javascript operator " | " with numbers

Tags: javascript, operators

Hi i just want to know how works this operator in this case...

```
<html>
<head><title></title>
<script>

var ff=23|1|3|65|1|25;
    //result 95
    alert(ff);

why the result is 95?

</script></head>
</html>
```

Why the result is 95? what is the procceses?

Comment: [MDN Bitwise OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.7C_(Bitwise_OR))

Answer (score 2):

`|` stands for Bitwise OR operator. The result of bitwise or of all those numbers is 95.

Apply binary OR operation over all these numbers

```
0010111    - 23
0000001    - 1
0000011    - 3
1000001    - 65
0000001    - 1
0011001    - 25
-------
1011111    - 95
```

and the result would be 95. The Truth table for Bitwise OR is as follows

```
+-----------+
|   | 0 | 1 | 
-------------
| 0 | 0 | 1 |
------------- 
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 
-------------
```

You can even check the step-by-step results, like this

```
23 | 1
// 23
23 | 3
// 23
23 | 65
// 87
87 | 1
// 87
87 | 25
// 95
```

Comment: @WearFox Glad to have been of help :) Please consider accepting this answer if it helps you :)